# DFS is not hitting every node as it traverses down

Tags: java, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to count the longest chain of nodes in a directed acyclic graph.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
for (Node n: nodes){
    max[n.index] = depth-first-search(n);
}

public static int depth-first-search(Node n){
    for (Node neighbor:n.Neighbors){
        return 1 + depth-first-search(neighbor);
    }
    return 0; //if no neighbors, return 0
}
```

So we test some input:

```
Vertex -> Neighbors
Node 1 -> 3
Node 2 -> 0
Node 3 -> 2
Node 4 -> 1, 2, 7
Node 5 -> 3, 1
Node 6 -> 4
Node 7 -> 0
```

Now we are populating an array with the longest chain of neighbors for each vertex, so if we do this by hand we get the following:

```
Node 1 = Length of 2 (3, 2)
Node 2 = Length of 0
Node 3 = Length of 1 (2)
Node 4 = Length of 4 (3, 2, 1, 7)
Node 5 = Length of 3 (2, 3, 1)
Node 6 = Length of 5 ( 2, 3, 1, 4, 7) <-Longest 
Node 7 = Length of 0
```

If I run it through my program, the array looks like this:

```
Node 1 = Length of 2 <- Correct
Node 2 = Length of 0 <- Correct
Node 3 = Length of 1 <- Correct
Node 4 = Length of 3 <- Off by 1
Node 5 = Length of 2 <- Off by 1
Node 6 = Length of 4 <- Off by 1
Node 7 = Length of 0 <- Correct
```

I went ahead and traced the algorithm for Node 6 and noticed that it ignores the Node 7. Here's the trace:

```
dfs(6)
   return 1+dfs(4)
      return 1+ dfs(1)
        return 1+ dfs(3)
         return 1+ dfs(2)
          return 0
```

As we can see, it never hits Node 7 and it's not clear to me why. I tried changing the line, "return 0" to "return 1" in depth-first-search() and it did fix the lengths that were off by one, but it put all of the previously correct lengths over by 1. If anyone could shed some light it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is in the loop of your neighbors.  It only ever checks the first because you have a return statement.  You probably want to not return, but remember the maximum of the neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

You only see one neighbor because of the return statement.  You need to check all of the neighbors.

```
public static int depth-first-search(Node n){
    int max = 0; //if no neighbors, return 0
    for (Node neighbor:n.Neighbors){
        max = Math.max(max, 1 + depth-first-search(neighbor));
    }
    return max;
}
```

Update:

I don't think your expected answer is correct:

```
Node 1 = Length of 2 (3, 2)
Node 2 = Length of 0
Node 3 = Length of 1 (2)
Node 4 = Length of 4 (3, 2, 1, 7)
Node 5 = Length of 3 (2, 3, 1)
Node 6 = Length of 5 ( 2, 3, 1, 4, 7) <-Longest 
Node 7 = Length of 0
```

the correct solution should be

```
Node 1 = Length of 2 (3 -> 2)
Node 2 = Length of 0 ()
Node 3 = Length of 1 (2)
Node 4 = Length of 3 (1 -> 3 -> 2)
Node 5 = Length of 3 (1 -> 3 -> 2)
Node 6 = Length of 4 (4 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2) <-Longest 
Node 7 = Length of 0 ()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I've made the changes and I'm still getting the incorrect results. Actually, it looks like Node 5 is displaying the correct length of 3 now, but the rest of the nodes with the off by 1 issue are still having the same problem.

Comment: Here's the lengths I'm getting now:
2
0
1
3
3
4
0

Comment: Node 7 is a neighbor of Node 4 as well: 

Node 4 -> 1, 2, 7

Comment: Right, but that isn't in the longest path.  If you start at 4 you can go to either 1, 2, or 7.  At 1 you can only go to 3, at 2 you have no where to go and at 7  you have no where to go.  So all of your options are `(4 -> 1 -> 3)` or `(4 -> 2)` or `(4 -> 7)`.  Since `(4 -> 1 -> 3)` is the longest, you choose it.  There is no path that starts with 4 and includes both 1 and 7 because those are separate paths.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but for this particular problem we want to include every neighbor we can reach. So we start at Node 6, we can reach Node 4. From Node 4, we can reach 1, 2, and 7. From Node 1, we can reach 3. We end up with 5 nodes we can reach by starting at Node 6: 4, 1, 2, 3, 7. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Then you question is misleading, because what you are describing isn't longest chain.  Doing as you describe means you need to return more data each time.  Instead of returning an int, you would need to return a set of nodes because we don't want to count duplicates.  Look at node 5, you would be counting 3 twice, once for node 5 and once for node 1.  So, the algorithm would need to change to union the result set from each neighbor.  The final step would be to return the size of the set.